# How do you find the probability of $P(X\le23|X>13)$ if any?

Tags: probability-distributions

Let X be a continuous rv with PDF
$$Fx(X) =\begin{cases}4x^3  &  0<x≤1 \\ 0  & \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$After many tries, I've come to the conclusion that the answer is zero since the  question is asking us to find a probability that is outside the given interval. Anyone have any other idea or is my answer right?

Comment: $P(X>13)=0$. Thus, taking the definition of a conditional probability, you would have to divide by 0 ?!?

Comment: That was supposed to be the interval of 0<x≤1 and 0 otherwise

Comment: @JeanMarie i think you get $0/0$ which you can take the limit to show it is $1$ in that case.

Comment: @gt6989b What limit are you taking?

Comment: @Jean Marie.. I was wondering if I should even get to that point since the whole question is asking us to find the probability of values outside the interval

Comment: @gt6989b I took the limit 23 and 13 and integrated, but I got a probability way above 1

Comment: @gt6989b how did you get 0/0?

Comment: Not understanding what's going on with the discussion here. $P(X>13) = 0$ and the conditional probability with respect to an event with zero probability is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Your PDF has support only on $[0,1]$ so $X$ lies between $0$ and $1$ with probability one: $$ P(0\le X\le 1) = 1.$$ This means in particular that $$ P(X>13) = 0$$ (if it's between zero and one it's definitely *not* greater than thirteen) and $$ P(X\le 23)=1$$ (if it's between zero and one it's definitely less than or equal to twenty three).

If you tried to apply the naive formula you'd get $$P(X\le 23\mid X>13) = \frac{P(X\le 23)}{P(X>13)} = \frac{1}{0}$$
so that's a problem. You're trying to take a conditional probability with respect to the event $X>13,$ but that event has probability zero. This is why in the fine print of the definition of [conditional probability with respect to an event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#Conditioning_on_an_event), it stipulates that the event you're conditioning on must have nonzero probability. Otherwise the conditional probability is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I think you really mean $f_X(x)$, not $F_X(x)$, and the proof is that
$$
\int_0^1 4x^3dx = 1.
$$

Now that figured out, note that by definition, $$\mathbb{P}[X \le 23] = F(23)$$ and $$\mathbb{P}[X>13] = 1 - F(13),$$ where
$$
F_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f_X(s)ds.
$$

Can you

1. finish the integral to get an expression for $F_X(x)$;
2. plug your event into the definition of conditional probability and evaluate the probabilities in the numerator and denominator of the resulting expression;
3. simplify the result to find the answer?

Comment: Yes of course, it is pdf, not a cdf. But I am not sure that the exercice is intended to make use of the cdf.

Comment: Yes, I wrote the function wrong. Let me try to solve, thanx

Comment: @gt6989b...I'm not getting probability equal to or less than 1 for F(23)